# Neural Networks and a catalogue of the number of floating point operations in various types of statistical and time series models

Tags: neural-networks, forecasting, time-complexity

I recently came across this paper [Green AI](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10597).

In the paper they discussed using floating point operation (FPO) count during testing and implementation of Neural Networks (NNs) to compare the efficiency of various NNs.

I would like to look at this topic more generally. Mostly from a forecasting perspective where naive, state space, and auto regressive models are used heavily.

I would like to know if there exists information on the FPOs to calculate these simple models and if this does not exist are there estimation techniques to get to a rough idea of this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found computational complexity of various machine learning algorithms, but I did not find FLOPs.

Here is the link https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine/learning/computational-complexity-learning-algorithms/